# Auto push android apk to google play using google play service

Tags: android, batch-file, ant, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin

I want to push android apk to google play using google play service in automated way.

As of now I am building  my android app using Ant and windows batch scripts and able to get the .apk file without any manual intervention.

Now I want to upload the generated .apk file to google play using google play services with help of ant and windows batch scripts in automated way.

When I google i come to know that by using gradle I can do it, but I am unable to build my project using gradle. So, I don't want to go this way.

I am able to push .apk to google play manually using my google play developer console. 
Now I what to automate this process, How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a bit of handling required with the Google Play Services API, for which the Windows batch commands are likely insufficient.

Since you don't want to change your project to Gradle, have you given a bit of thought to using Jenkins? It can be a light weight "provisioning" server on your system, that achieves what you want by using the [Jenkins Google Play Android Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin) (see the complete step by step instructions). The good part is you don't have to change your Ant project. You can in future even automate more of your dev-test-deploy cycle by leveraging more of Jenkins capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Fastlane (and Supply in particular): https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply#readme

Basically, it's a command-line tool to upload binaries, screenshots and changelogs to Google Play.